# How to join downloaded file parts

Tags: python, file, download-manager

So , I am trying to download a single file in parts using the Python `Threading` module and `requests` to download.

Now the thing is I am able to download the file into four separate parts but not able to join them.

I tried using `PyPDF2` to join pdf and `ffmpeg` to join video files but no help. I am not able to open any of the downloaded files which explains that they are not getting downloaded correctly.

`PyPDF2` giving error

> PdfReadError: EOF marker not found

What should I do so that that I am able to join the files correctly.
Secondly , do I have to use seperate methods to join them, Or I can implement one method which can be used for different file formats
Below is the `download` function I implemented.

```
def download(threadId, drange, url):
    headers = {"Range":"bytes={0}-{1}".format(drange[0], drange[1])}
    print headers

    size = drange[1] - drange[0]
    print "Starting Thread {0}".format(threadId)
    req = requests.get(url, headers=headers, stream=True)

    download_status[size] = size
    download_status[threadId] = 0
    # return req
    with open('test{0}.mp4'.format(threadId), 'wb') as f:
        for r in pr.bar(req.iter_content(chunk_size=2048), expected_size=(size/2048)+1):
            if r:
                f.write(r)
                f.flush()
```

Comment: I think that if you only need to download a file separated in 4 portions, then registering it on your system, if you receive the 4 parts in a binary block, you can simply do open('output', 'ab') for append-binary to write the received part at the end of the already-received file parts.

Comment: I tried downloading it by changing `'wb'` to `'ab'` but out of the 4 parts the first part is getting downloaded as mp4 and rest as binary.

Comment: I agree with @Artemis in that you only need to 'chain' the blocks. Why don't you first try it with some tiny local example (no download involved). Just split a small file manually and try to join it with your code. If the results match, then try to implement the same with a download. You might have a problem with the ranges (the last bit of the range might not be included and you're assuming it is or the opposite). Just use something simple that you can manually check, a random chunk of bytes, a 1x1 image...

Comment: When opening the file for reading/sending it over the network, or even on local, don't use some fancy libraries. There are just too much formats available here and you can't just do some spagetti-code for every filetype. Instead open the file using the native `open('file', 'rb') function` then keep using the `'ab'` argument on the receive side. It should work fine. Use @martinarroyo's example before anything else, it may help you see where it actually fails.